# Is there a way to cut up a live music recording by clicks?

Tags: python, audio

I'm new to coding in Python and so I'm wondering if it's feasible to record our band's performances and separate the live recordings by the drummer's clicks? They click between every song.

I've looked through numerous libraries, but I'm unsure of how I'd go about starting. My current idea is to check for drops in volume and the frequency of the clicks to decide a split in the audio file. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Why would you do that? Is it too many songs to do it by hand?`

Comment: We perform every month so I want to automate it

Comment: It heavily depends on your songs, if you have silence in some of them the thing will break. If the clicking is not done equally every time, it will fail. If you have like 20 songs, than thats 20 mousclicks in your daw to slice the audio. Calculate that against the time consumption of automating this. If you want to do some crazy project just for fun, you should go for it :)

Comment: Judging by the waveform there's no silence. Is it unrealistic to think that making Python look at 2s intervals of a song and checking for 2 consecutive clicks to split a song to be feasible?